# Block UI using session

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have used jQuery to block the UI and display a loading image while the page is loading.Here is the code I have used :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").bind("click",function(){
    $.blockUI({ message: '<p id="loading">`<img src="http://localhost/admin-ci/admin/css/flexigrid/images/load.gif" />` processing...</p>'});
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 15000); 
    });
});
</script>
```

It is working absolutely fine.The issue is my senior has now asked me to block the UI using session!!!I have no clue how to do it and couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Not sure what you mean *block the UI using session*. Can you possibly elaborate?

Comment: just use SESSION values in if conditions....no idea what are you findin difficult to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the session

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loading'])) { 
$_SESSION['loading'] = 1; 
} 
else {
$_SESSION['loading'] = 0;
}
?>
```

Write your javascript code,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").bind("click",function(){
    <?php if ($_SESSION['loading'] == 0) { ?>
    $.blockUI({ message: '<p id="loading">`<img src="http://localhost/admin-ci/admin/css/flexigrid/images/load.gif" />` processing...</p>'});
    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 15000); 
    <?php } ?>
    });
});
</script>
```

After loading, you can again set the session value as

```
$_SESSION['loading'] = 1;
```